# Derivative of variables vs functions

Tags: derivatives

Edit: Removed specific equation.

General question is: How are variables and functions treated differently during differentiation?

Comment: The "auto-solver" you are using doesn't know that $y$ is a function of $x$, so it's treated as a constant

Comment: What is $y$ ? A function of $x$ or a constant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be right or wrong, depending on what $y$ means in the context.

If *$y$ is a function of $x$*, let us write it explicitly $y(x)$, then:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x-y(x))^3=3(x-y(x))^2\left(1-\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$

If *$x$ and $y$ are independent variables*, and you are only differentiating on $x$, then you are treating $y$ as a constant during differentiation. However, then *this is called *partial differentiation* and you should've used the symbol $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$*:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x-y)^3=3(x-y)^2$$

because when differentiating $x-y$ on $x$ only, the derivative of $x$ is $1$ and the derivative of the (constant) $y$ is $0$.